# Solr 8.1 replication with invalid master error after setting up

Tags: solr

I followed the article (https://medium.com/@hanyshehata/sitecore-setup-using-solr-master-slave-index-replication-6417cdd98eaa) to set up solr (8.1.1) master/slave on scaled environment. While I got the following error on slave server. Not exactly sure what is wrong with that. Much appreciated if anyone can help with that.

[image]

Comment: What is your replication handler part of config on Slave?

Comment: @MarekMusielak , Thanks for your comments and I added these code blocks in slave .   
  `<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">              <lst name="slave">  
  <str name="masterUrl">https://ip address/solr/sitecore_core_index</str>  
  <str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>  
  <str name="compression">internal</str>   
  <str name="httpConnTimeout">5000</str>   
  <str name="httpReadTimeout">10000</str>   
   </lst>   
 </requestHandler>   `  Wondering if there is something i missed? Thanks !

Comment: Have you included port number in `masterUrl`? Can you access that url from web browser on your slave server? Have you added `master` replication on Master server as well? can you add config from that part as well?

Comment: @MarekMusielak  yes, port no. is included, while i  indeed can not access the url with expected result. It returns 404 actually. Anyway, with another instance,it works fine in UAT server even i can not access that url which return the same 404 error. so i wonder if we have to get 200 status to finally set up the replication.

Comment: @MarekMusielak it works now and it's really weird as I did nothing except stop and start, and previously i just restart  solr. That's the only difference as far i can find. Thanks for your support anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have missed something in your configuration in `solr.config` file either on `master` or on `slave` server.

Here is a sample configuration for `<requestHandler` section for `master` server:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
  <lst name="master">
    <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
    <str name="backupAfter">optimize</str>
    <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt,elevate.xml</str>
    <str name="commitReserveDuration">00:00:10</str>
  </lst>
  <int name="maxNumberOfBackups">2</int>
  <lst name="invariants">
    <str name="maxWriteMBPerSec">16</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

and here is sample configuration for `slave` server:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
  <lst name="slave">
  
    <!-- fully qualified url for the replication handler of master. It is
         possible to pass on this as a request param for the fetchindex command -->
    <str name="masterUrl">https://master.solr:8983/solr/sitecore_core_index</str>
  
    <!-- Interval in which the slave should poll master.  Format is HH:mm:ss .
         If this is absent slave does not poll automatically.
  
         But a fetchindex can be triggered from the admin or the http API -->
  
    <str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```